# need suggestions in selecting a variable range in excel macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set in Sheet1 in my Excel file (data.xlsx). I want to perform a set of advance filter action in Excel macro and store the filtered data in Sheet2.  The criteria conditions are given in "X1:X2", "Y1:Y2" and in "Z1:Z2" in Sheet1. The paste range in given in Sheet2 at A1:X1, A11:X11 and A21:A21.

I tried the following code, but it's not working. Please give me suggestions to do that.

Code :

```
Sub AdvFilter() 

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    j=1 

    For i = 1 To 3  

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _     
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, (23+i)), _   
        Cells(2, (23+i))), CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet2"). _   
        Range("A" & j, "X" & j), Unique:=False 

    j=10+i 

    Next i  
End Sub
```

Comment: what happens when it is "not working", eg error messages? bad results?

Answer (score 0):

`Cells(1, (23+i))` refers to the ActiveSheet: if Sheet1 isn't active when you run that code it will fail.

It's best to always be explicit when referring to ranges.

```
Sub AdvFilter()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim rng As Range, sht1 as worksheet

    Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")

    j=1 

    For i = 1 To 3  

    Set rng = sht1.Cells(1, (23+i)).Resize(2,1)

    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _     
        CriteriaRange:= rng, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet2"). _   
        Range("A" & j, "X" & j), Unique:=False 

    j=10+i 

    Next i  

End Sub
```